# What Java web services frameworks support RPC/Encoded messages?

Tags: soap, axis

I have tried several Java frameworks, but I only found out that Axis 1 supports these messages, but Axis 1 is old and not developed anymore. So I would like to know if there are any Java frameworks that support RPC/Encoded messages and are still supported and developed.

Comment: I think that's it. RPC/Encoding isn't part of the modern web service standards.

Comment: Same problem here, I'm stuck on this for like a week...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Axis1.4 is the only option as RPC/encoded SOAP should be old - old and no longer developed framework shoudln't be a problem

http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#ServiceStylesRPCDocumentWrappedAndMessage